# Extracting site/location name from a site description column

Tags: r, stringr

I have 300,000+ rows of waterquality samples, that I am trying to extract waterbody names from for a waterbody column.

```
wbod_data<- data.frame(smpl_ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                         site_loc = c("Nile River at bridge", "MC-M1", "Red ROBIN CREEK 30 M D_S OF STP", "PT068 SCUTTLE LK #2", "FORDING R BELOW HARE CREEK"),
                         waterbody = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

Many of the samples identify the related waterbody as part of a site description field as seen in site_loc. There is a high degree of variability in formatting of the waterbody names, with different naming conventions (River or R), different orders (Station_ID before waterbody name), different object lengths (Red Robin Creek versus Nile River) and multiple waterbodies referenced (FORDING R BELOW HARE CREEK). Some samples have no relevant information such as MC-M1.

For the needs of the project, not every row will have waterbody data, and it is fine if some available data is missed but I am trying to figure out a way to extract as much usable watershed data as possible. My approach so far has used Str_extract to extract the keywords as well as preceding word.

Given a keyword list as follows,

```
site_list <- wbod_data$site_loc
wtrbdy <- c("River", "CREEK", "LK", " R ")
keypone <- paste0("([^\\s]+\\s+){1}", keywords)
keypone_list <- paste(keypone, collapse = " | ")
print(wbod_data$waterbody <- str_extract(site_list, keypone_list))`site_list <- wbod_data$site_loc
wtrbdy <- c("River", "CREEK", "LK", " R ")
keypone <- paste0("([^\\s]+\\s+){1}", keywords)
keypone_list <- paste(keypone, collapse = " | ")
print(wbod_data$waterbody <- str_extract(site_list, keypone_list))
```

This results in:
"Nile River "   NA              " ROBIN CREEK " " SCUTTLE LK "  NA

There are a few issues with this. One is that obviously I miss instances of 3 word names, such as RED ROBIN CREEK. Another is whatever is happening with row 5. I'm not sure if it is how I called for R as a vector, or if it has to do with there being more than 1 vector instance in the string.

Any guidance on how to properly call for 1 letter strings such as R, as well as potentially extract instances of 3 word strings would be much appreciated.

Comment: No easy way to do this via regex alone.  Case in point: `FORDING R BELOW HARE CREEK` ... how do we know that the creek name is `HARE` alone and not `BELOW HARE` ?

Comment: I'd be happy to help with this Christopher, but you would have to provide more rows of data, (so that I can be sure that my answer is robust)